# How can I use references with Perl6::Form?

Tags: perl, reference

I'm trying to print tabular data with [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form), but I'm not sure how to output data from hash references. Here's what I tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Perl6::Form;

my @alerts; 

push @alerts, { site => "192.168.0.1", status => "200", id => "QWE" };
push @alerts, { site => "192.168.0.2", status => "500", id => "QER" };

print form
        ' ====================================== ',
        '| ID          |    SITE    | STATUS    |',
        '|-------------+------------+-----------|',
        '| {[[[[[[[[[} |{[[[[[[[[[} | {>>>>>>>} |',
           \@alerts{id}, \@alerts{site},\@alerts{status},
        ' ====================================== ';
```

Comment: Try for example: `$alerts[0]->{site}` it should give `"192.168.0.1"`

Comment: I want to use Form package, and print all entries, [http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Form/lib/Perl6/Form.pm#Array_data_sources]. To be honest I'm not sure it's doable in this way.

Comment: @Gregory Nisbet, This is a Perl 5 question. Perl6::Form is a module for Perl 5 (that provides forms similar to Perl 6's).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need parallel arrays.

```
my @ids      = map { $_->{id}     } @alerts;
my @sites    = map { $_->{site}   } @alerts;
my @statuses = map { $_->{status} } @alerts;

print
   form
      '+=======================================+',
      '| ID          | SITE        | STATUS    |',
      '|-------------+-------------+-----------|',
      '| {[[[[[[[[[} | {[[[[[[[[[} | {>>>>>>>} |',
         \@ids,        \@sites,      \@statuses,
      '+=======================================+';
```

We can eliminate the code duplication.

```
my %dbf;   # Data by field
for my $field (qw( id site status )) {
   $dbf{$field} = [ map { $_->{$field} } @alerts ];
}

print
   form
      '+=======================================+',
      '| ID          | SITE        | STATUS    |',
      '|-------------+-------------+-----------|',
      '| {[[[[[[[[[} | {[[[[[[[[[} | {>>>>>>>} |',
         $dbf{id},     $dbf{site},   $dbf{status},
      '+=======================================+';
```